# Google Slides Translations

Tags: google-docs, animation, slideshow

I'm using Google Slides on my tablet, and I don't know how to add transitions and animations to slides. Is there any solution or app doesn't have option for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some editing options are only available on the most recent version of the Google Slides app. But anyway, it seems that transitions have not be implemented to enlighten the app on less powerful devices like tablets and phones.